# Create multiple S3 lifecycle rule conditionally

Tags: terraform

I am trying to create a `aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration` resource but only if `bucket_lifecycle` variable is not empty. Current code works fine and create multiple rules within single lifecycle configuration but it is failing if bucket_lifecycle variable is empty (no aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration is expected)

Current code:

```
locals {
  bucket_lifecycle     = { for k, v in var.lifecycle_rules : k => v }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "this" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.this.id

  dynamic "rule" {
    for_each = local.bucket_lifecycle

    content {
      id     = try(rule.value.id, null)
      status = try(rule.value.enabled, true) ? "Enabled" : "Disabled"

      dynamic "filter" {
        for_each = try(rule.value.prefix, null) == null ? [] : toset(["0"])

        content {
          prefix = lookup(rule.value, "prefix", null)

          and {
            tags = lookup(rule.value, "tags", null)
          }
        }
      }

      dynamic "expiration" {
        for_each = lookup(rule.value, "expiration", {})

        content {
          date                         = lookup(expiration.value, "date", null)
          days                         = lookup(expiration.value, "days", null)
          expired_object_delete_marker = lookup(expiration.value, "expired_object_delete_marker", false)
        }
      }

      dynamic "noncurrent_version_expiration" {
        for_each = lookup(rule.value, "noncurrent_version_expiration", {})

        content {
          noncurrent_days = lookup(noncurrent_version_expiration.value, "days", null)
        }
      }

      dynamic "noncurrent_version_transition" {
        for_each = lookup(rule.value, "noncurrent_version_transition", {})

        content {
          noncurrent_days = lookup(noncurrent_version_transition.value, "days", null)
          storage_class   = noncurrent_version_transition.value.storage_class
        }
      }

      dynamic "transition" {
        for_each = lookup(rule.value, "transition", {})

        content {
          date          = lookup(transition.value, "date", null)
          days          = lookup(transition.value, "days", null)
          storage_class = transition.value.storage_class
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried to change it to:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "this" {
  for_each = length(local.bucket_lifecycle) > 0 ? local.bucket_lifecycle : {}

  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.this.id

  dynamic "rule" {
    for_each = each.value
...
```

but that doesn't work, throwing list of errors like:

```
Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first argument.
```

The module configuration looks like:

```
module "s3" {
[...]
  lifecycle_rules = [
    {
      id = "first"
      enable = true
      prefix = "*/path1/"
      expiration = [
        {
          days = 1
        }
      ]

      noncurrent_version_expiration = [
        {
          days = 1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id = "second"
      enable = true
      prefix = "*/path2/"
      expiration = [
        {
          days = 1
        }
      ]

      noncurrent_version_expiration = [
        {
          days = 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
  policy = ""
}
```

Comment: Try swapping your `for_each = length(local.bucket_lifecycle) > 0 ? local.bucket_lifecycle : {}` for `count = length(local.bucket_lifecycle) > 0 ? 1 : 0`. Also, I'm not sure how `for k, v in var.lifecycle_rules : k => v` works when `var.lifecycle_rules` is just a plain list - what are `k` and `v` then?

Comment: @lxop count and for_each can't coexist within the same resource.

Comment: Right, which is why I suggested swapping, not adding